# Add events to gcal via command line?

Tags: command-line

I'd like to know how to add events to my Google Calendar via command line. What's the best way?

Comment: You might want to check out [khal](http://lostpackets.de/khal/), which is a CalDAV command line calendar client

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can do it. To do this we have tool named as `gcalcli` . 
by typing as `gcalcli editor` you can have a calender which is editable.

Look at its manpage for more information : [gcalcli-manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/man1/gcalcli.1.html)

If its not installed , to install it type as `sudo apt-get install gcalcli` in your terminal and then you can install & use it.

to give  more understanding on usage I have found one good link which can help you.

[google-calender-howto](http://www.maketecheasier.com/manage-google-calendar-from-command-line/2010/08/05) and this link have everything for you.

Comment: This looks ideal. I'm a relative beginner, can you explain how to install it?

Comment: @begtognen I have edited my answer and added some good link too . check it out my friend.